# C ++: How to write to multiple files with different names every loop?

Tags: c++, file, loops, filenames

I have a program where I created the output:

```
std::ofstream OutA("A.dat");
```

There is a loop in this program where data is created to put in A:

```
for ( k = 1; k < n_iterations ; k++ ){
OutA << Data_for_A << std::endl;
}
```

However, now I wanted to do another loop.

The evolution of the values ​​that I will put in A depends on a variable, T.
So, I'll make several tables for different T. There will be a loop like this:

```
for ( T = 0; T < x; T = T + 0.5){
    for ( k = 1; k < n_iterations ; k++ ){
    OutA << Data_for_A << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But it would be convenient if, as the loop changed the value of T, it would write in  different files with different names, according to the variable T.

Example:

- The first time you run the loop, pass the data to "OutA1.dat", the second time "OutA2.dat" and follow with the indexes 1,2, ...
- Or that the indexes are not 1,2, ... but rather the values ​​of T. Thus: "OutA_T0.dat", in the next "OutA_T0.5.dat", with indexes varying T = 0,0.5 , 1.1.5, ...

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Convert `T` into a string, and use it to construct the file name. Then just create an `std::ostream` with that file name.

Comment: If `x` is a known number or something with a predictable and reasonable upper bound, you can pregenerate all the names and read them out of a table as required.

Answer (score 0):

use std::to_string function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string Data_for_A() {
    return "hello";
}

int main() {
    double x = 3;
    int n_iterations = 5;

    for (double T = 0; T < x; T = T + 0.5) {
        string name = "OutA_T" + std::to_string(T) + ".dat";
        std::ofstream OutA(name.c_str());
        for (int k = 1; k < n_iterations ; k++ ) {
            OutA << Data_for_A() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the difference if I use "name" instead of "name.c_str()"?
I tested here and it gave me the same result.

Comment: @GabrielHenrique There isn't a difference here, and the `.c_str()` is unnecessary. Like most other functions in the C++ standard library, the constructor of `std::ofstream` has overloads to take both `std::string`s and C-style strings.

Comment: `string` is in the `std` namespace, just like `ofstream`. You might as well just use `std::` everywhere and remove the `using namespace std;`, which is bad practice.